# Android: olt Memory Leak reported by Eclipse Memory Analyzer

Tags: java, android, eclipse, memory-leaks

I analyzed my `hprof` file for memory leaks in Eclipse today, and I noticed that one of the biggest offenders is a resource I am not familiar with.

```
    One instance of "olt" loaded by "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x421c26c8" occupies 
7,877,440 (13.76%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of 
"java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry" loaded by "<system class loader>".
```

What is olt? And why is it accumulated in a HashMap? Even looking at the path to GC root, I don't see any references that are meaningful. Instead, there are more weird acronyms like nnu, olw, oiy, olu etc...

Is there anything meaninful to be gleaned from this leak suspect?

Comment: Are you using proguard?

Comment: @MichaelKrause no actually for this project I am suprisingly not right now, and I just double checked that there are no proguard references in my gradle.